# Async download image and set to imageview

Tags: android

Alright, I'm fairly new to android development and am working on an app.  I've looked all over stackoverflow but can't seem to find an example which works.  I need to download a photo from a url asynchronously and then set it in an imageview.  I decided to create a class separate from my fragments to download the images.

Code:

```
public class UpdateUser {

    private static final String TAG = "UpdateUser";


    public void refresh(JSONObject user){

        //Download profile pic
        try {
            downloadProfpic(user.getString("userpic_url"));
        }  catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }
    }

    public void downloadProfpic(String userpicURL) {

        try{

            URL murl = new URL(userpicURL);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(murl.openConnection().getInputStream());

            Context context = Application.getContext();
            final FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("Prof_pic.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);

            //Set the imageview
            //pageFrag.setProfPic("Prof_pic.png");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }    

    }
}
```

As you can see its not asynchronous and also doesn't set the imageview.  Also I'm fairly sure I'm not doing it correctly.  Should I be downloading to internal storage?  Or download to a file?  Could someone please help me.

Thank you,
Tom

Answer (score 3):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Or, use [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion).

Or, use [SmartImageView](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/).

Or, use any other existing Android library for downloading and processing images.